# Counting the number of values for each row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I created a function in SQL that counting the number of LocationIDS the function getting location ID and returning how many times that locationID exist in the TABLE.

My issue is when I'm calling that function in my stored procedure - it is displaying it for each row instead of showing one column

Let's say for example in my table:

```
LocationID  NumberofshippingLocation
------------------------------------
    48                 2 
    48                 2
    52                 1
```

Instead of merge the ones that shown twice to one

```
LocationID  NumberofshippingLocation
-------------------------------------
    48                 2    
    52                 1
```

Query:

```
-- Select [dbo].[fnGetNumberOfShippingLocations](52)

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetNumberOfShippingLocations](@ShippingLocaitonID Int)
RETURNS VarChar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @rValue INT

    Select @rValue =  COUNT(*) 
    From GSACPeopleBadgeRequest
    Where ShippedLocationID  = @ShippingLocaitonID

    Return @rValue 
END
```

The call from my stored procedure is like this:

```
[dbo].[fnGetNumberOfShippingLocations](PBR.ShippedLocationID) AS 'NumberOfShippingLocation'
```

Comment: Did you try SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Your source table already contains the number of shipping locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a GROUP BY clause.

This counts the number of records per `ShippedLocationID` (result = 2, for id=48):

```
SELECT
    @rValue = COUNT(*) 
FROM
    GSACPeopleBadgeRequest
GROUP BY
    ShippedLocationID 
WHERE
    ShippedLocationID = @ShippingLocationID
```

If you need the sum instead of just the number of records, do this (result = 4, for id=48):

```
SELECT
    @rValue = SUM(NumberofshippingLocation)
FROM
    GSACPeopleBadgeRequest
GROUP BY
    ShippedLocationID 
WHERE
    ShippedLocationID = @ShippingLocationID
```